# Flow not Updating New Case Fields - Email-to-case

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-experience, case, email2case

We are trying to auto-update field values on a new case, which was created by email-to-case.

Our Org has several email-to-case addresses and we want the email address the case was sent to, to determine the values of certain fields.

To keep debugging simple let's limit this flow to one of the support addresses as the one resource.

#### Resource

- configurations

  - Type = Constant
  - Data Type = Text
  - API Name = EmailAddressResource
  - value = "emailaddress@domain.com"

#### Start Element

- configurations

  - Object = Case
  - Configure Trigger = "A record is created"
  - Optimize the Flow for = "Fast Field Updates"

##### Next Element

#### Update Record Element

- configurations

  - How to find records to update and set their value = "Use the Case record that Triggered the Flow"
  - Set filter conditions = "All Conditions Are Met (AND)"

    - Field = {!Record.source:EmailMessage.ToAddress}
    - Operator = "equals"
    - Value = "EmailAddressResource"
  - Set Field Values for the Case Record

    - Field = Department__c
    - Value = "Staffing" (Text from picklist)
    - Field = Region__c
    - Value = "APAC"

#### End Element

This flow works in debug mode but does not update the fields in deployment
    when an email message is received to the specified email address and the case
    is created.

In the past when a flow worked in debug mode, but not in deployment, there was
    a conflict with another automation.

However, in this case I have reviewed all other automations and can not find
    any potential conflicts. The resource used in the filter condition is not used
    in any other flow instances and there are no other attributes of these email
    messages/cases that are used in other flows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope that your day is off to an amazing start. This is happening because of the order of operations and where your Before Flow (Fast Field Updates) lies in the said order of operations. We recommend changing it to Actions and Related Actions and using a decision node so you don't have to query for records that meet certain conditions in your Update element. Please try the following and report your results. Thank you and have a blessed one.

**Resource**

- configurations
- Type = Constant
- Data Type = Text
- API Name = EmailAddressResource
- value = "emailaddress@domain.com"

**Start Element**

- configurations
- Object = Case
- Configure Trigger = "A record is created"
- Optimize the Flow for = "Actions and Related Records"

**Next Element**

**Decision Element**

- Label & API Name = Whatever you desire
- Condition Requirements to Execute Outcome = All Conditions Are Met (AND)
- Resource :

  - Field = {!Record.source:EmailMessage.ToAddress}
  - Operator = "equals"
  - Value = "EmailAddressResource"
- When to Execute Outcome = If the condition requirements are met
- Outcome Order

  - Case from "Name of EmailtoCase Name"
  - Not created from "Name of EmailtoCase Name" (This is the default and should have nothing under its outcome details)

**Next Element Under the Case from "Name of EmailtoCase Name" Branch**

**Update Element**

- Label & API Name = Whatever you desire
- How to Find Records to Update and Set Their Values

  - Use the case record that triggered the flow
- Set Filter Conditions

  - None Always Update Record
- Set Field Values for the Case Record

  - Field = Department__c
  - Value = "Staffing" (Text from picklist)
  - Field = Region__c
  - Value = "APAC"

**End Element**